# How do i post python varaibles using curl?

Tags: python-3.x, curl

for instance i have the following

```
title = "some title"
name = "name"
headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
data = '{"title": title,"name":name,"action":"save"}'
response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.7:8080/news/save.json', headers=headers, data=data)
```

i want to post the title and the name to a database with those fields, and they both will keep on changing .
I execute this statement and it works without any errors, but when i see my database, these fields arent there yet.
If i hardcode the title and the name then it works fine.

Comment: Try printing your 'data' variable. You'll see you are not adding 'title' and 'name' to the 'data'.

Comment: Please provide more details about the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

- Not sure what does this have to do with curl
- You are sending an hardcoded string that has nothing to do with the defined variables. You should create a json and send that:

  ```
  import json

  title = "some title"
  name = "name"
  headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
  data = json.dumps({"title": title, "name": name, "action":"save"})
  response = requests.post('http://192.168.1.7:8080/news/save.json', 
                           headers=headers, data=data)
  ```